# Convert linear gradient from Mozilla to Chrome

Tags: css

I am having some problems converting a linear gradient for viewing in Chrome. It would be a bonus to see this gradient for full cross-browser too if you're willing, I'm developing a theme and it would help tremendously.

Here's the Mozilla version here:

```
background:
  -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #401746 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 250%) repeat scroll 0% 0% #6e2778;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, import gradient, this is what you get.  I do wonder how that %250 stop location would be handled cross browser, though.  It might not strictly be valid across browsers.

```
background: #401746; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzQwMTc0NiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjI1MCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNmZmZmZmYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #401746 0%, #ffffff 250%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#401746), color-stop(250%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #401746 0%,#ffffff 250%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #401746 0%,#ffffff 250%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #401746 0%,#ffffff 250%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #401746 0%,#ffffff 250%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#401746', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Edit: Nevermind about my color stop worries (see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/, section 4.1.1. linear-gradient() syntax, second to last paragraph):

> The gradient's color stops are typically placed between the starting point and ending point on the gradient line, but this isn't required - the gradient line extends infinitely in both directions. The starting point and ending point are merely arbitrary location markers - the starting point defines where 0%, 0px, etc are located when specifying color-stops, and the ending point defines where 100% is located. *Color-stops are allowed to have positions before 0% or after 100%.*

Emphasis, my own.